# How can I get the selected columns set from the Univocity CsvParserSettings?

Tags: univocity

Situation:

- import wizard is creating CsvParserSettings instance with all selected columns definition
- CsvParserSettings being handed over to Task to run CsvParser in new Thread
- need to set there conversions per selected column

Question:

- is there a way to get from CsvParserSettings the selected indexes

Note: method `public FieldSet<Integer> selectIndexes(Integer... fieldIndexes)` is used to define the selection rather to read it back

Alternative solution: provide also Array of column indexes